# Why my ruby application works locally and does not run on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, postgresql-9.1

I have a Ruby 1.8.7 application that works correctly locally. To load it on Heroku, I changed the database from SQLite to PostgreSQL, install PostgreSQL 9.1.3, I changed the Gemfile replacing gem `sqlite3` with:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

And changing the part production of `config/database.yml` with:

```
production:
adapter: postgresql
database: project_production
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

Then I run `bundle install --without production` successfully. Next I created a git repository with:

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m "text"
```

Later I create a heroku application with `heroku create --stack bamboo-ree-1.8.7` , `git push heroku master` and `heroku rake db:migrate` successfully.

But it didn't work!

What's missing? I've done something wrong or I have not made ​​any statement?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not an error message create by neither Rails nor Postges nor Heroku. You might want to be a wee bit more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "git add *" working ? I think you'd better use :

```
$ git add .
```

As Larsenal asked, could you post your logs ?

```
$ heroku logs
```

The basic information about heroku deployment is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3).

You don't need the "production" block in database.yml, this is automatically generated by heroku when deploying.

Kind regards,
Max

Comment: I have tried to create a new git repository with the command "git add." and upload it to Heroku.
Logs have given the following errors:
- ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (could not find Setting with ID = 1) when, instead, file "seeds.rb" there "Setting.create (: id => 1, ...)"
- ...
- GET app.heroku.com status = 404

Comment: it is possible that Heroku does not automatically load the file seeds.rb? How can I do?

Comment: For your information, you can also use : `bundle exec rake db:setup` which will create the database, load the schema and then load the seed data.